# Weird casting related issue in java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

consider the following code:

```
public class ListDemo {

    List<Inner> inners;

    public ListDemo() {
        this.inners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void load(){
        SomeClzz.load(inners);
    }

    private class Inner implements TestInterface {

        @Override
        public void bla() {
            System.out.println("Bla");
        }

    }
}
```

with the interface:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    public void bla();
}
```

and the class:

```
public class SomeClzz {
    public static void load(List<TestInterface> test){
        for (TestInterface testInterface : test) {
            testInterface.bla();
        }
    }
}
```

I created this fake code based on a real world example, because I wanted to see if I could isolate the issue and found the that the load method had an error.

Why is it that `SomeClzz.load(inners);` gives an error that inners can't be cast from a `List<Inner>` to a `List<TestInterface>`?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: @nickb I edited the question to specify the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple change will make it work:

```
public static void load(List<? extends TestInterface> test){
    for (TestInterface testInterface : test) {
        testInterface.bla();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You can find the answer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

In short.

`List<Inner>` is not a subtype of `List<TestInterface>`.

This is a common misunderstanding when it comes to programming with generics, but you need to understand this, as generics are very important frequently used.